# using a PLUG-IN to exisitng testing framework or using FULL FRAMEWORK - which do you recommend?

Tags: c#, testing, automation, junit, qtp

Say you have a huge automation project and are using a certain testing framework, say -JUnit for most of the automation. However you typically get stuck with automating the flash part of the the application . Now you can usually select several tools for that issue only. on the one hand tehre are tools that are standalone and include all framework elements (such as If, database queries, multiple test runs etc) and others that are plugins that solve the specific flash problem  but require to use the framework (e.g.JUnit) for creating s full blown test (mainly data queries and loops).
Which would you recommend to use? what are the pros and cons from your experience in such situations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I like using the same framework as the one I use for the unit tests  (with extra components added into the mix to be able to do tests like the above).

I find it easier for the team to switch, collaborate and contribute at different levels.

Test automation involves developer skills, imho keeping it in the same platform makes your life easier.